# iptables: ! matching multiple ip addresses

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, ip, routing

I need to redirect packets coming from outside of my network (5.9.0.0), so I try to add this action on one of the computers (it has three interfaces 5.9.30.20, 5.9.20.20, 5.9.10.20), but I get `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING –p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply ! -d 5.9.0.0/16 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.9.40.10
```

As far as I've googled, that's because my computer is in 5.9.30.0/24, 5.9.20.0/24 and 5.9.10.0/24 and 5.9.0.0/16 is one step up.

So I tried this way as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING –p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply ! -d 5.9.30.0/24,5.9.10.0/24,5.9.20.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.9.40.10
```

but I got `iptables: ! is not allowed with multiple IP addresses`

Can I check that the packet's destination/source is not 5.9.10.0/24, 5.9.20.0/24 or 5.9.30.0/24 somehow?

Comment: Are you sure that it makes sense to use DNAT on ICMP echo-reply packets? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: netfilter and iptables don't know about routes, they only manipulate addresses. So it's fine to try and NAT, but you have to ensure your *routes* are compatible with the result: `Network is unreachable` tells that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Independent of my doubts about what you are trying to do there:

You can check several addresses separately:

```
iptables -t nat -N dnat_operation
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j dnat_operation
iptables -t nat -A dnat_operation -d 5.9.30.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A dnat_operation -d 5.9.10.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A dnat_operation -d 5.9.20.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A dnat_operation # do whatever with the packets which are left
```